# How to get Token with java

Tags: java, jwt

I'am new in JWT so i need to get a token with JAVA code from a webService (GET Method).

In postMan i was able to get the token (below the screenshot).
[image]

I used this java code but this return often `Response Code : 403`

```
String url = "https://WEBSERVICE_LINK";
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        this.log.info("Sending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);

        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + pwd).getBytes()));

        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        this.log.info("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        StringBuilder response;
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuilder();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
        }

        String reponseString = response.toString();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(reponseString);

        // Isoler et transmettre le Token
        this.token = jsonNode.get("token") != null ? jsonNode.get("token").asText() : null;
        this.log.info("Token : " + this.token);
```

Thank you

Comment: did you tried adding Bearer before token? like this - "Bearer " + authToken

Comment: I need the Token so you mean like that `con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + pwd).getBytes()));
` ?

Comment: yes try adding Bearer before token

Comment: I have also `RESPONSE 403` despite it worked in postman with the same login and PWD

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten the `Basic`  prefix in the `Authorization` header value:

```
con.setRequestProperty(
  "Authorization",
  "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + pwd).getBytes())
);
```

Comment: I used to add this but i have always the same problem                        
`con.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic c3BNjpVNWJlNW0zTA==");`

Comment: `c3BNjpVNWJlNW0zTA==` doesn't look right, it doesn't decode to `<username>:<password>`.

Comment: (And careful posting passwords online ;)

Comment: Also i used this `private final String auth = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + pwd).getBytes());` then `con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", this.auth);` and i have the same problem

Comment: This should do though, are you sure `username` and `pwd` hold the expected values?

Comment: Yes i am sure i don't know why i have `403` despite it worked in POSTMAN